# Beginner Java Task file writer

Tags: java, file, append

I am trying to make a java program that appends text into an existing document. This is what it has gotten me at:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Main
{
    public main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter a task: ");
        Scanner taskInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String task = taskInput.next();
        System.out.print(task);

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("res\tasks.txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.println("The first line");
        writer.println("The second line");
        writer.close();
    }

}
```

I have some errors and do not know how to fix them. I looked at the Bufferedwriter but I don't know how it's used, and yes I have looked javadocs. C++ was not nearly this complicated. Once again, I want to know how to make the program append text to an existing file. It should be efficient enough to make into an app. Are there any good resources to teach how to write/append/read files?? javadoc is not doing it for me.

Comment: What errors you came across?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main()` method in Java has to have the following signature

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Without the method being declared as above, JVM would fail to run your program. And, just like you closed the `PrintWriter`, you need to close your `Scanner` too.

I suggest you get the basics of Java down before diving into File I/O because this API would throw a lot of checked `Exception`s too and for someone this new to Java it would just be terribly confusing as to what the `try catch`s or `throws` are doing.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("tasks.txt", true)));
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Formatter out = new Formatter("fileName.txt");
            out.format("Write this to file");
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred");
        }
    }
```

This is using a Formatter object to create a file (if it doesn't already exist) and then you can use the method "format" just like you would use any print method to write to the file. The try and catch is necessary for it to compile b/c the constructor of the Formatter class throws an exception that must be caught. Other than that, just make sure you type: 
`import java.util.Formatter;`in the beginning of your file.

And btw, C++ is NOT easier than Java lol. Cheers.